# Closure var not capture string

Tags: swift

This code is not working, how do I repair it?

I try to handle the `string` and return it, but no result. printing does not output anything to the console

[image: Image of error in thread]

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let x = "hello"
        let viewm = viewmodel()
        viewm.handler(x)
        viewm.handler = { item in
            print(item)
        }
        viewm.execute { (tt) in
            print(tt)
        }
    }
    class viewmodel {
     var handler:(String) -> Void = {
         (data: String) in
    
    }
    func execute(complete: @escaping (String) -> Void) {
        self.handler = complete
    }
}
```

Comment: Your execute method just saves the completion handler away, and then returns without doing anything. It neither does any useful work, nor ever invokes the completion handler. What are you **trying** to do?

Comment: I am trying to pass data from a controller, first to one view model and then to another. but I do not quite understand how to do it better. @DuncanC

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what you are trying to achieve here, but if your issue is that `print(item)` is not printing anything, that is happening because this code by itself is not going to print anything:

```
viewm.handler = { item in
   print(item)
}
```

`handler` property is a closure that receives a String parameter and returns Void. On your `viewDidLoad` method, you are assigning a closure that complies with those characteristics and, in addition to that, is going to print the passed parameter.

Given that closures are self-contained blocks of functionality, you need to call it in order to execute its block of functionality; but you need to call it after it has been defined; otherwise, it is not going to print anything.

If you write your code in this order, "hello" is going to be printed.

```
viewm.handler = { item in
  print(item)
}
viewm.handler(x)
```